# Android stop infinite loop/repetition in Carousel CoverFlow (moondroid)

Tags: java, android, carousel, coverflow

Is there any way to prevent infinite loop/repetition in Moondroid Coverflow (https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow).

Automatically connecting the last object to the first object once it gets to the end.

Used below property for prevent infinite loop :

**setShouldRepeat(false);**

seems to do nothing other than break the coverflow when there are less than four objects. It completely prevents scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have got from reported issues on this library :
https://github.com/applm/CarouselWidget/issues

Endless feature is hardcoded in this component.
Take a look here
https://github.com/applm/CarouselWidget
I started moving features there. but not finished yet.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Do you have any idea about other library which is helpful.

Comment: It depends on what exactly you need .. please check this links : [link](https://github.com/crosswall/Android-Coverflow?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=3530) , [link](https://github.com/binaryroot/CarouselView?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=3991) , [link](https://github.com/bhaveshjabuvani-credencys/CarouselEffect?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=5525) , [link](https://github.com/sayyam/carouselview?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=3289) .. Hope this help you :)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @Mohammed Gomaa

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try to write this in your onResume :

```
youradapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```